# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: CDIExtension

Tags: java, spring, jersey, websphere-liberty

I have created two Jersey servlet projects using `com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet`. I use jersey 1.19.1 jars. Both projects has the dependent jars in lib folder. I deployed both the projects in liberty 9 server.
When I try to access the endpoints, one project works fine but not the other one. I have below exception in console if second project does not work. If I restart that project alone (not the server), it works. I do not know why and I try to find the permanent fix for this.

> SRVE0271E: Uncaught init() exception created by servlet [jersey-servlet] in application [secondproject]: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: CDIExtension
>
> SRVE0315E: An exception occurred: java.lang.Throwable: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet

If first project does not work, I see the below exception in console.

SRVE0271E: Uncaught init() exception created by servlet [jersey-servlet] in application [firstproject]: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension incompatible with com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension

SRVE0276E: Error while initializing Servlet [jersey-servlet]: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet

Update with full stack:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: CDIExtension
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.getInitializedExtension(CDIExtension.java:183)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIComponentProviderFactory.<init>(CDIComponentProviderFactory.java:95)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIComponentProviderFactoryInitializer.initialize(CDIComponentProviderFactoryInitializer.java:76)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.configure(WebComponent.java:572)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.configure(ServletContainer.java:332)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:604)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:332)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadOnStartupCheck(ServletWrapper.java:1428)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.doLoadOnStartupActions(WebApp.java:1181)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinally(WebApp.java:1149)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:1055)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:6499)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApp(DynamicVirtualHost.java:446)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.createRunnableHandler(DynamicVirtualHost.java:248)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.createRunnableHandler(DynamicVirtualHost.java:313)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl.discriminate(VirtualHostImpl.java:251)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:300)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:471)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:405)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:285)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:256)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:174)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:83)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:929)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1018)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
    Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: CDIExtension
        at com.ibm.ws.jndi.internal.ContextNode.lookup(ContextNode.java:218)
        at com.ibm.ws.jndi.internal.WSContext.lookup(WSContext.java:297)
        at com.ibm.ws.jndi.WSContextBase.lookup(WSContextBase.java:62)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.getInitializedExtension(CDIExtension.java:181)
        ... 33 more




Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension incompatible with com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.getInitializedExtension(CDIExtension.java:181)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIComponentProviderFactory.<init>(CDIComponentProviderFactory.java:95)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIComponentProviderFactoryInitializer.initialize(CDIComponentProviderFactoryInitializer.java:76)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.configure(WebComponent.java:572)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.configure(ServletContainer.java:332)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:604)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:332)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Provide full stack trace.

Comment: I am just getting these two lines in the console.

Comment: full stack trace is included below

Answer (score 5):

Please check [this link](https://ralph.blog.imixs.com/2012/07/20/glassfish-3-1-x-cdiextension-not-found/), it is helpful to me.

You can solve the problem when setting the system-property 
`com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.lookupExtensionInBeanManager=true`

This can be done from the GlassFish server console.

1. Select the node ->Configuration->server-config->JVM Settings
   change to the tab ‘JVM Options’
2. add a new entry

   -Dcom.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.lookupExtensionInBeanManager=true
3. restart your server

Answer (score 0):

In the logs you can see:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension incompatible with com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension
```

Liberty uses Jersey as JAX-RS provider, so you have conflict. You either have to remove these jars from your application, or make sure that JAX-RS feature is not included explicitly or implicitly in your server.xml

Answer (score 0):

The error,

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'com.sun.jersey.config.CDIExtension'. Resolved 'com.sun.jersey.config'; remaining name 'CDIExtension'
```

can be caused due to an class import in EJB3
Example:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;

@RequestScoped
public class SampleServices {

@EJB
CalcBeanLocal calcBean;
.....
```

When importing **RequestScope** "bean.xml" will be added to WEB-INF.

This ca be resolved by using **@stateless** annotation instead of @RequestScope and by removing the above created "bean.xml" in WEB-INF.

Example:

```
@stateless
public class SampleServices {

@EJB
CalcBeanLocal calcBean;
.....
```